# Billing on careers site doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Today, I try to look, what is my payments option for Careers. And I get error.

- Click on "unfiled" on Status page
- URL: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/billing/jobseekers
- error: This webpage has a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoopsie daisy.  Sorry about that, it should be fixed now.  Thanks for the report.